# DEFAULT local variables vs Initialized local variables with DECLARE in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, default, local-variables, declare

First, I experimented the `DEFAULT` local variable `value` which has `2` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
  value INTEGER DEFAULT 2; -- Here
BEGIN
  IF value = 2 THEN
    value := 4;
    RETURN value;
  ELSE
    value := 2;
    RETURN value;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, `my_func()` returned `4` twice without `4` and `2` alternately as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------
       4
(1 row)
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------
       4
(1 row)
```

Second, I experimented the initialized local variable `value` which has `2` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
  value INTEGER := 2; -- Here
BEGIN
  IF value = 2 THEN
    value := 4;
    RETURN value;
  ELSE
    value := 2;
    RETURN value;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, `my_func()` returned `4` twice without `4` and `2` alternately as shown below:

```sql
apple=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------
       4
(1 row)
apple=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------
       4
(1 row)
```

So, what is the difference between `DEFAULT` local variables and initialized local variables?

Comment: [plpgsql declarations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html): *The DEFAULT clause, if given, specifies the initial value assigned to the variable when the block is entered. If the DEFAULT clause is not given then the variable is initialized to the SQL null value. The CONSTANT option prevents the variable from being assigned to after initialization, so that its value will remain constant for the duration of the block.* So basically just another way of saying `value INTEGER := 2`. Each time you run the function you will start with `value INTEGER := 2`

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to save a value, save it to a table. To persist it for the duration of a session, make it a `temp` table. For transaction, `temp...on commit drop`.

You can also use [custom parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html) and alter them from inside the function.

```sql
set my.var=2;
```

Otherwise, your `value` variable lives only for the duration of the function and it's reinitialised individually for each call.

```
set my.var=2;

CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER AS $f$
BEGIN
  IF current_setting('my.var',true)::int = 2 THEN
    set my.var = 4;
    RETURN current_setting('my.var');
  ELSE
    set my.var = 2;
    RETURN current_setting('my.var');
  END IF;
END;
$f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select my_func();
```

| my_func |
| --- |
| 4 |

```sql
select my_func();
select my_func();
select my_func();
```

| my_func |
| --- |
| 2 |

| my_func |
| --- |
| 4 |

| my_func |
| --- |
| 2 |

[Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8G-tFp4-)